# How to create a self-starting C++ systemd service with CPackDeb?

Tags: c++, cmake, systemd, cpack, debhelper

I'm new to Debian packaging and I believe this is a fairly basic question, but I am embarrassed to say I've struck out on Google.

I have a C++ project which builds with CMake and packages a debian with CPack. This project has a service component (systemd style). My goal is to have the service enabled & auto-started upon installation of the package.

My research has yielded two approaches:

1) Run various `systemctl` commands inside the {pre,post}{inst,rm} scripts in the Debian. Care is required to handle install, remove, and upgrade scenarios properly.

2) Simply put the `project.service` inside the `debian` directory and let `debhelper` (with [dh_systemd_enable](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_systemd_enable.1.en.html)) handle service installation and start 'automagically'.

Option #2 is obviously preferred because the {pre,post}{inst,rm} is very manual and thus error-prone, but I cannot figure out whether there's a well supported way to leverage `debhelper` from within CPack.

**The Question:** I'd like to avoid rewriting the debian packaging stuff in my project's CMake as it's been around for some time and works well. The relationship (if any) between `CPackDeb` and `debhelper` is not clear to me -- can CPack take advantage of the `dh_systemd_enable` features or must I manage the service manually in {pre,post}{inst,rm} scripts?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?